# Installation of Visual F# tools for vs 2012 express is failing

Tags: f#

Installation of Visual F# Tools for VS2012 express on our Windows Servers (with 2008 R2) is failing with "FSharp.ProjectSystem.Base dll - Signature or catalog could not be verified or is not valid"
[Installation Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQonD.png)

Could anyone please suggest on the fix. Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't use VS2015 Community edition instead?

Comment: I agree with John. VS 2012 is also nearing end of mainstream support soon. Therefore using VS 2015 at least Community Edition is more recommended than using VS 2012.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Since those are production servers which have .net framework 4.0, that was the only option I was left with.. Else I'll have to upgrade the framework as well. but I am hesitating as it is a prod server which some clients like oracle already installed - not sure if they break ..